# API Gateway, Lambda, Cognito CORS Issue

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am getting the following error: ***Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.***

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1IGn.jpg)

On my localhost:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "TOKEN");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://XXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev?text=india", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Enabled CORS on API Gateway:
[Options CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tI8t.jpg)

Lambda with proxy integration returns:
[Lambda return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd9av.jpg)

Code was running fine without Authorization in GET method.

API returns the required result in Postman with Authorization header.

Comment: Did you re-deploy the modifications to the stage after you made them?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:  Anytime APIGW complains about a "preflight" issue, it's referring to the OPTIONS method.  Also, Postman usually works because it doesn't have the same CORS restrictions as browsers.

I think the actual problem is that you cannot combine `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 'true'` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` (wildcard).  If you are allowing credentials, you must set an actual origin.

Here is an MDN page that talks about it
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials